# GidView Responsiveness in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

I am trying to make this Grid items responsive in Flutter web, on changing the size of browser but somehow it is not behaving in my expected way. Is there any better way to achieve the same functionality.

[image]

Below is the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double itemHeight = ResponsiveWidget.isSuperLargeScreen(context)
        ? 120
        : ResponsiveWidget.isLargeScreen(context)
            ? 120
            : ResponsiveWidget.isMediumScreen(context)
                ? 30
                : ResponsiveWidget.isCustomSize(context)
                    ? 30
                    : 196;
    final double itemWidth = ResponsiveWidget.isSuperLargeScreen(context)
        ? 200
        : ResponsiveWidget.isLargeScreen(context)
            ? 250
            : ResponsiveWidget.isMediumScreen(context)
                ? 45
                : ResponsiveWidget.isCustomSize(context)
                    ? 45
                    : 309;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.68,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 140, right: 140),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight)                       ),
                  itemCount: gridItemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _gridlistitem(
                      gridItemList[index].route,
                      gridItemList[index].image,
                      gridItemList[index].title,
                      gridItemList[index].iconData,
                      index,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Some of the values are just hardcode for the purpose of this question.

These are the screen sizes:

```
const int largeScreenSize = 1566;
const int calendarSize = 1200;
const int mediumScreenSize = 500;
const int smallScreenSize = 360;
const int customScreenSize = 1100;
const int superlargeScreenSize = 1720;
```

Comment: I would prefer using wrap while item size will be based on screen width, or changing the crossAxisCount on gridView